# Suspension of a Representation

Tags: reference-request, manifolds, book-recommendation, fiber-bundles, foliations

**Geometric Theory of Foliations**, authors **Cesar Camacho** and **Alcides Lins Neto**, Chapter **5**, Pages **95**.

Does anyone know some highly recommended references on the theorem in the image below?

[image]